# Why do i have vignette around my photos?

Tags: nikon, landscape, nikon-d3300

I have recently purchased a Nikon 18-105mm VR lens for my D3300. I took photos with it today and there are dark patches in the corner of each photograph.

I was not using any filters or a lens hood.

Settings: f/8, focal length: 105mm - ISO: 200 - shutter: 1/1000

Could someone please tell me what this is?

Comment: Please include example photos - there's very little we can do to help without seeing examples.

Answer (score 1):

Lens Reviews tested this lens and found some interesting results, see here.

http://www.imaging-resource.com/lenses/nikon/18-105mm-f3.5-5.6g-ed-vr-dx-af-s-nikkor/review/

The main point is near the bottom,

> Shading (''Vignetting'')
>   The 18-105mm does show some evidence of
>   corner shading, but its presence is fairly subtle. If you demand
>   absolutely no corner shading in images produced by this lens, you'll
>   have to use it at apertures of ƒ/11 or smaller; larger apertures
>   result in some form of corner shading. Using a focal length of 35-50mm
>   will help; these focal lengths are a bit more forgiving, and will only
>   produce significant corner shading when the lens is used at apertures
>   wider than ƒ/8.
>
> At the focal length extremes, upwards of 2/3 of a stop of corner
>   shading can be seen when the lens is used at its largest aperture.

and also here

> If there's a weakness in the lens at all, it would be performance at
>   105mm, where image sharpness doesn't quite reach the level seen at
>   other focal lengths. However you'd be hard-pressed to see the quality
>   difference in practical use.

The lens received high praise over all from the reviewer, but did state the same issues you discussed.